# How else can i write the code, using for loop in c++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

Can someone help me how else can I write the code provided below for the following task using c++?
"Using for loop.
Get two integers, a and b, from the user.
Print the list of odd numbers in the range [a, b]."
I'm a beginner, so I can't figure out, how to do it properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector <int> odd_numbers(int a, int b) {
    vector <int> odd_numbers_list;
    for (a; a < b + 1; a++) {
        if (a % 2 != 0) {
            odd_numbers_list.push_back(a);
        }
    }
    return odd_numbers_list;
}

void showList (vector <int> g) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < g.size(); ++i) {
        cout << g.at(i) << "; ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main() {
    cout << "input 2 numbers" << "\n";
    int a;
    int b;
    cin >> a;
    cin >> b;
    vector <int> x = odd_numbers (a, b);
    showList(x);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have shown?  Do you get compile errors, does it crash, does it give the wrong results, etc.

Comment: Its ok, but i want to know, how it can be done in another way, maybe to simplify something

Comment: You may want to print numbers immediately in the same loop, rather than put them to a container. This will make the program smaller, but will also make it less modular: compuation and output will not be separate...

Comment: Another way to write the loop would be to find the first odd number greater than or equal to `a` and loop from there until the value is greater than `b`, incrementing by 2 each time: `if (a % 2 == 0) ++a; for ( ; a <= b; a += 2) { /* do something with a */ }`.

Comment: @Gilex There really isn't that much there to comment on because there isn't that much there. It's like asking for an art critique of a cube drawn in line art without shading. I do like that your `odd_numbers` function is a pure function. It's a minor thing but it'd be nice if you were at least consistent with your naming conventions. You use snake case for `odd_numbers` but lower camel case for `showResults`. This lack of consistency might not seem like a big deal with a few dozen lines of code but they can start becoming jarring with a few million trying to remember how things are named.